# JS Regex Get Multipe groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following Text, I want to extract Rock Smash & Dig from the below text. I tried this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/glvUNb/1), but it doesn't seem to work..

`str:`

```
__**Cubone  100%**__Panama

Despawns @ 03:40:33am __**(29m 55s)**__
Weather Boost: **Clear :sunny:**
Level: 19 - IV: 100% (15/15/15) - CP: 5120
- **Rock Smash**
- **Dig**

**Map Info**: https://maps.google.com/?q=35.1224486753,-106.6278869713


var getRegex = /(?:-\s+\*+)[\w\s\w]+/mg;

var res = getRegex.exec(str);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/glvUNb/2

Comment: Doesn't work, gives only the last line i.e Dig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add 2 times `\w` in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), you could just add it once `[\w\s]`.

Try it like this with a capturing group

[`(?:-\s+\*+)([\w\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/1qtHbe/1)

Or like this:

[`- \*\*([^*]+)\*\*`](https://regex101.com/r/4hygU8/1)

Your matches are in group 1 `([\w\s\w]+)`.

Then you could loop the matches:

```js
var regex = /(?:-\s+\*+)([\w\s\w]+)/g;
var str = `__**Cubone  100%**__Panama

Despawns @ 03:40:33am __**(29m 55s)**__
Weather Boost: **Clear :sunny:**
Level: 19 - IV: 100% (15/15/15) - CP: 5120
- **Rock Smash**
- **Dig**

**Map Info**: https://maps.google.com/?q=35.1224486753,-106.6278869713`;
var m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: And If I also want to get `29m 55s` from `Despawns @ 03:40:33am __**(29m 55s)**__`, then how can i? I tried few workarounds, but they are all useless

Comment: @Aka One way to do it might be like this [`(?:- |__)\*\*([a-zA-Z \d()]+)\*\*`](https://regex101.com/r/vJBk5z/1). That would like the allowed characters in a character class.
Or [`(?!^)(?:- |__)\*\*([^*]+)\*\*`](https://regex101.com/r/nwdejy/1).

Comment: Thank you, understood it now :)